# How to design a mechanism to manage viewcontrollers transitions, like route

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to design a routing mechanism for management view controller transitions in objective-c.

Two view controllers, without reference to the other side of the pointer, the transition is completely controlled by the route.

How to achieve the route?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you think like this.

Route = Segue (In Xcode)

1. Take Two View controller
2. Make 1st Embed in Navigation controller (Which is must be initial View Controller)
3. Put One Button in 1st VC
4. Press Ctrl + Drag Mouse from button to 2nd VC (One popup will be show, then select Push)
5. Run Project
6. Press Button

Lol

Comment: Yes,exactly what you sayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Storyboard's segues. Create view controllers and segues between them. You can use `Push Segue` or `Model Segue`. Push Segue will let you pop next view controller too, and you will have to embed your first view controller into navigation controller. For `Model Segue`, you can move from one view controller to another but to return to previous view controller, you will have to create another segue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the approach to  answer this question。 Here is the similar [project](https://github.com/clayallsopp/routable-ios).